# ¿Existen alternativas a Offset y Position para que "ocurra algo" al llegar a una posición determinada?

Tags: javascript, offset

Offset y Position de jquery me estan dando demasiados dolores de cabeza. No toman en cuenta los margenes y en conclusion me estan calculando muy mal la posicion. Remuevo los margenes y me siguen calculando mal. No se que pasa. Entonces quiero saber si alguien aqui sabe de algun "truco" o alternativa para que "ocurra algo" cuando llegue a una posicion determinada. Por ejemplo: Tengo 3 bloques, uno encima de otro, y quiero que cuando baje al bloque numero dos, se ejecute algo, digamos un alert, cualquier cosa. Pero quiero hacerlo sin Offset ni POsition. ¿Se puede hacer? ¿Existen alternativas?

Comment: Hola @natan, te sugiero que pongas un ejemplo con código acá para que te podamos ayudar, ya que poniendo así el problema dudo que sepamos que quieres hacer y como. Saludos!.

Comment: Hola , pero es que mi codigo es muy grande y resultara confuso. Simplemente entiende este ejemplo por favor: Tengo 3 contenedores , uno sobre otro..Yo quiero que cuando baje el scroll o la pagina hasta el inicio del contenedor numero 2, ocurra un evento, digamos un alert...Pero esto no quiero hacerlo con offset ni position, porque como digo, me esta calculando fatal...QUiero saber si hay alternativas, algun truco que alguien sepa.

Comment: hace un [mcve] que demuestre el problema.. tal vez solo estas haciendo un mal calculo...